Не открывается порт на Windows Server 2019
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
В учреждении есть автоматизированная информационная система, есть в интернете сайт, на котором можно заказывать талоны к врачам. Меня попросили открыть порт (например, :1234) на сервере и пробросить на роутере, правила везде прописал. Т.е. сайт, на котором пациент будет заказывать талоны, будет через роутер стучаться на сервер. Не сервере через команду netstat -a проверил, открыт ли порт, но его в списке вообще нет, на сайте i2p порт по ip-адресу сервера тоже закрыт. Что я не так делаю?
На скрине изображено правило для роутера во второй строке (откуда будет идти трафик, т.е. с какого ip сайта(порт не знаю, поэтому любой), на сервер ip-сервера и открытый порт)

Не уверен, что ты на нужной вкладке, но тебе нужна штука под названием "port forwarding". Как это называется у зухелей - не знаю.
